# mysql create a treewalking list

Tags: sql

**Create a treewalking list of every
employee's last name, his manager’s
last name, and his position in the
company
The top level manager has position 1,
this manager's subordinates position 2,
their subordinates position 3, and so on Start the listing with employee number
100**

[image result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTin4.png)

`SELECT LEVEL "POSITION", e.last_name, e.manager_id "Manager Name" FROM employees e START WITH e.employee_id = 100 CONNECT BY PRIOR e.employee_id = e.manager_id ORDER SIBLINGS BY e.last_name;`

[the result of the code above but the manager name is different from photo number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjSMM.png)

Comment: Seems easy, what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @ysth
**I already made it but it looks different in the (name manager) section**

Comment: `SELECT LEVEL "POSITION", e.last_name, e.manager_id "Manager Name"
      FROM employees e
      START WITH e.employee_id = 100
      CONNECT BY PRIOR e.employee_id = e.manager_id
      ORDER SIBLINGS BY e.last_name;`

Comment: I don't know what that is, but it isn't mysql.  please tag with the database you are actually using instead

Comment: https://www.udrop.com/67vK/SQL_Schema.sql   @ysth

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEVEL AS "Position", e.last_name, PRIOR e.last_name AS "Manager name"
FROM employees e START WITH e.employee_id = 100 
CONNECT BY PRIOR e.employee_id = e.manager_id;
```

use this to show manager name